# Dynamically Change Bootstrap Progress Bar Value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, axios

First of all, apologise if I couldn't explain properly. Please do comment so I can explain again if something missing. Will really appreciate any kind of help

I am trying to implement a bootstrap progress bar dynamically in my react upload component while send a post request by using axios.

At the moment what I implement it's directly going to 95 per cent and then done

But I am looking to implement like this example:

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=dynamically-change-bootstrap-progress-bar-value

my full component will be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/7mgtkub3/

```
 sendRequest(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const dataForm = new FormData();
      dataForm.append("datafile", file, file.name);
      var self = this;
      self.setState({
        uploadProgress: 95
      });
      axios
        .post(
          `/api/dataset/${this.props.spreadSheetData._id}/upload`,
          dataForm,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
          }
        )
        .then(function(response) {
          self.setState({
            uploadProgress: 100
          });
          //console.log("SUCCESS!!");
          self.props.formSubmitted(response.data, 3);
          let filesToUpload = self.state.filesToUpload.slice();
          filesToUpload = filesToUpload.filter(fileObj => {
            return fileObj.name !== file.name;
          });
          self.setState({
            filesToUpload: filesToUpload
          });
          let toastMsg = {
            msg: file.name + " is uploaded successfully",
            className: "lobibox-notify-success"
          };
          notify(toastMsg);
        })
        .catch(function() {
          //console.log("FAILURE!!");
          self.setState(
            {
              uploadState: "Error"
            },
            () => {
              let toastMsg = {
                msg: file.name + " is not uploaded",
                className: "lobibox-notify-error"
              };
              notify(toastMsg);
            }
          );
        });
    })
      .then(response => {})
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  <div className="Content">
            {this.state.uploadProgress > 0 ?  <ProgressBar
               // now={uploading}
               // label={`${uploading}`}
               now={this.state.uploadProgress} 
               label={`${this.state.uploadProgress}%`}
                animated now={this.state.uploadProgress}
              /> : ""}
```

Comment: Sorry it's a react-bootstrap/ProgressBar not a bootstrap progress bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About your question**

You need subscribe on upload process progress event. 
If you use axios, you can try `onUploadProgress` method.

Modify you code like there:

```
.post(
  `/api/dataset/${this.props.spreadSheetData._id}/upload`,
  dataForm,
  {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => self.setState({
         uploadProgress: progressEvent.loaded
      })
    }
  }
)
```

(You may need to change calculated upload progress function)

**Some other words**

You don't have to create new Promise on the second line of your code. Axios already return Promise, and you can return result of axios:

```
const dataForm = new FormData();
      dataForm.append("datafile", file, file.name);
      var self = this;
      self.setState({
        uploadProgress: 95
      });
      return axios // .....
```

Comment: Oleg thanks a million for your help I tried what you explain but it not working some reason would be able to see my component which is here: https://jsfiddle.net/7mgtkub3/

as I am new in React can't figure it out what's going wrong  thanks a million

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't debug your code, because it doesn't launch. I only see  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` in console.

But I see that you don't insert `onUploadProgress ` callback in your code

Comment: thanks for your reply

As i am not using any calculated upload progress function I just declare uploadProgress in the state then set the uploadProgress:95 befor making the request and then while request finish set uploadProgress: 100 

so what you say do I need to create a method like this 
``calculatedUploadProgress = (progressEvent) => {
    var percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
  } 

and after that how I will call it thanks  a million

Comment: You need not to only create method `calculatedUploadProgress`. You should inject this method in axios config (third argument of `axios.get`, near `headers`).  You can write something like this: `onUploadProgress: calculatedUploadProgress` where calculatedUploadProgress  is function that change state

Comment: Thanks a million, #Oleg
I figured it out that my API doesn't support dynamic changes so I need to make fake percentage for PrograssBar would it be possible and how If I can do with CSS how it would be thanks a million

Comment: It is difficult to make a progressBar with css. change your component state during file upload is right way. I don't understand your problem. If you make a  working sandbox with your code, I will help you.

Comment: Thanks a million, #Oleg I carate a sandbox here are the link and also please click the Project view icon in sandbox to see the output 

https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-platform-1rl3l

Comment: I have modified your code https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-field-uyhtn. First of all, you  forgot add file (maybe index.js), where you called `ReactDOM.render`.  I added this line in your code. Then I added the method discussed (lines 192-197).  But I Can't try how it work, because i have `TypeError`. It may be error in sandbox or in your code.  But you can repeat this lines in your local code, I think it will be work

Comment: Oleg thanks 
It does work now but the problem is it's always still 100% even though the file isn't finish uploading 
Can I do and if statement for this

Comment: Let's debug your code. Add breakpoint or console.log on 193 line ( codesandbox.io/s/runtime-field-uyhtn). Is breakpoint reached?  If it is true, you should debug state update event. Else, there is something wrong with axois config.

Comment: Doesn't reach the 193 lines just go until lines 192 anyway thanks for you help